# paypal api sandbox and live send error 10501 in second call

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i have weird problem with paypal api sandbox and live 
when i used it for first call it works just fine but in second call it gives me 1051 error 
here's my code

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');
$request_params = array
                (
                'METHOD' => 'DoDirectPayment', 
                'USER' => $api_username, 
                'PWD' => $api_password, 
                'SIGNATURE' => $api_signature, 
                'VERSION' => $api_version, 
                'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',                  
                'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'VISA', 
                'ACCT' => 'MYCARDNUMBER',                       
                'EXPDATE' => '092019',          
                'CVV2' => '456', 
                'FIRSTNAME' => 'mouner', 
                'LASTNAME' => 'mostafa', 
                'STREET' => '707 W. Bay Drive', 
                'CITY' => 'Largo', 
                'STATE' => 'FL',                    
                'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US', 
                'ZIP' => '33770', 
                'AMT' => '100.00', 
                'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD', 
                'DESC' => 'Testing Payments Prod' 
                );
 $nvp_string = '';
 foreach($request_params as $var=>$val)
 {
  $nvp_string .= '&'.$var.'='.urlencode($val);  
 }
 $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $result.'<br /><br />';
     curl_close($curl);
     $result_array = NVPToArray($result);
    echo '<pre />';
    print_r($result_array);
      function NVPToArray($NVPString)
     {
      $proArray = array();
      while(strlen($NVPString))
       {
       $keypos= strpos($NVPString,'=');
       $keyval = substr($NVPString,0,$keypos);
       $valuepos = strpos($NVPString,'&') ? strpos($NVPString,'&'): strlen($NVPString);
    $valval = substr($NVPString,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
    // decoding the respose
    $proArray[$keyval] = urldecode($valval);
    $NVPString = substr($NVPString,$valuepos+1,strlen($NVPString));
}
return $proArray;
}
```

and config file have my sand box url and api details

api response

```
Array
(
[TIMESTAMP] => 2016-08-22T00:53:51Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 9f0a90722a334
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 85.0
[BUILD] => 000000
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[AMT] => 100.00
[CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
```

Comment: can you provide the API response along with correlation id?

Comment: hello #vimalnath i updated my question with api response.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Sandbox account does not have a PRO account. you will need a pro account to run DoDirectPayment API calls.

I would recommend you to create another account from developer.paypal.com->Create Sandbox account->upgrade to PRO.

Comment: hello again :D in fact my sandbox account is already pro .thanks

Comment: can you try to make a dodirect api call now , it should work

Comment: from our end, it looked like the PRO was not enabled correctly, I have just re-enabled it. I am from PayPal .